# Error while storing data in couchbase saying "Value too large" with status code = 3

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, couchbase

I am facing a problem when storing list of objects into couchbase cache, i am using the following code :

```
 var status =  client.ExecuteStore(StoreMode.Add, "Tests", result);
```

and when checking property "StatusCode" it is returned by value "3" and error message "Value too large".

How can i fix this issue and store large data into couchbase?

Thanks in advance and any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message said, your document's value is too large - Couchbase has a maximum document size of 20MB for documents stored in Couchbase buckets and 1MB for those stored in memcache buckets.

See the [Data storage](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/index.html#data-storage) section in the Admin guide for more details.

Comment: I have some confuses about buckets used but i use default bucket (<servers bucket="default" bucketPassword="">) so it means that i have max 20 MB per key, so how can i split list of objects to be stored in different keys? and how can i check the size of list of objects before storing in order to check if to split or not ? can you help me please?

Comment: A single document can only be 20MB - Couchbase will not perform any splitting for you. You'll have to adjust your data model to split documents yourself if necessary.

Comment: Ok, but i face another problem when publishing website application at 2 different servers "A" & "B", installing CouchBase server at server "A" and share documents at server "A" so application at "A" & "B" will share same documents, the problem now that application at server "B" can't load documents from server "A" although config file of application at server "B" refers to bucket "Default" at server "A". is it required to install couchbase at server "B" also?

Comment: @Ahmy I suggest you start a new question for your new question.